# How to get CodeCommit pull request id form CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-event-bridge, aws-codecommit

The code I am working on is stored in a CodeCommit repository. I have set up an event in EventBridge that triggers a CodeBuild project to start building when a pull request is created. However, there is one issue - the build status of the CodeBuild project is not being displayed in the pull request's activity section.

I have searched but haven't found any solution related to CodeCommit repository. Most of them related to GitHub repository. However, there is a way to post comment from CodeBuild to the pull request and I am trying to follow the below link. But the problem is to configure the buildspec I don't know how can I get the pull request id when the event is triggered.

```
aws codecommit post-comment-for-pull-request --pull-request-id $PULL_REQUEST_ID --repository-name $REPOSITORY_NAME --before-commit-id $DESTINATION_COMMIT --after-commit-id $SOURCE_COMMIT --content "$content"
```

https://devato.com/post/codecommit-codebuild-pull-request-workflow

Can anyone give me some ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you use EventBridge input transformer to get pull request id from a codecommit pull request event and pass it to a codebuild project target? EventBridge StartBuild request has **environmentVariablesOverride** which can be used to store pr id as env var.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-transform-target-input.html